# How to override application.properties in Spring Boot integration test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, integration-testing

I've set up [integration tests with Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests) and want to use [Spring's "property inheritance"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). But the `application.properties` from `main` gets completely replaced.

Directory structure:

```
src/
  intTest/
    kotlin/my/package/
      SomethingTest.kt
    resources/
      application.properties
  main/
    kotlin/my/package/
      Something.kt
    resources/
      application.properties
```

The reason could be that I'm using `application.properties` (with the same file name) in the `intTest` *and* in the `main` directory. However, if I'm using a profile, let's call it "intTest" and a file called `application-intTest.properties`, it doesn't work either. The profile specific file is not picked up at all.

Gradle config:

```
sourceSets {
    intTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}

configurations {
    intTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    intTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'intTest'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.intTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.intTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
```

The test class (based on JUnit 5) is annotated with:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@ComponentScan
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

If I add `@TestPropertySource` to my test class the properties file is at least picked up:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations= ["classpath:application-intTest.properties"])
```

But the "properties inheritance" doesn't work either. So it is basically the same as using `application.properties` (without a profile part), what overrides all properties from `main`.

Adding `@Profile("intTest")` to my test doesn't solve the problem. The same applies for `@ActiveProfiles("intTest")`.

How can I use "properties inheritance" with my integration test setup?

Comment: If you name the test properties file application.properties then it overwrites the application.properties file because you have just one classpath. But using profiles works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was not my Gradle config but my IntelliJ config. The active profile has to be set in the run configuration -- namely for each and every run configuration in the integration test folder. This can be solved by annotating integration test classes with `@ActiveProfiles("intTest")`.